# Explicit example of countable transitive model of $\sf ZF$

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, foundations

Do we know any *explicit* example of a countable transitive model for $\sf ZF$ or $\sf ZFC$?

Comment: Why the vote to close? This seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. And yes.

$\sf ZF$, and by extension $\sf ZFC$, cannot prove their own consistency. Therefore within the confines of $\sf ZF(C)$ we cannot even prove that there are models of $\sf ZF$ to begin with.

Not only that. The statement "$\sf ZF(C)$ is consistent" is absolute between the universe and transitive models, so if there is a transitive model, not only that $\sf ZF(C)$, but also models of $\sf ZF+\operatorname{Con}(ZF)$ and much stronger theories.

So even if we assume the consistency of $\sf ZF$, we cannot prove that there are transitive models.

However! Just like $\Bbb N$ cannot be proved to exist just in $\sf PA$, we might as well take stronger theories instead of just $\sf ZFC$. And once a theory $T$, extending $\sf ZF$, proves that there exists *a* transitive model, then we know that there is a least $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$, and that $\alpha$ is countable. As far as explicit go, this is pretty damn explicit.

Comment: I know that $ZF$ cannot prove the Godel's statements that encode "ZFC is consistent" but we can't rule out the possibility that it can prove other statements that we know to imply consistency but are not the Godel's ones.

Comment: So... you're suggesting that ZF might not prove Con(ZF), but it will prove some $\varphi$ such that $\varphi$ implies Con(ZF). In that case, if you are assuming classical logic, modus ponens tells you that ZF proves Con(ZF).

Comment: Would an explicit exhibition of a model in our interpretation of ZF allow ZF to prove the Godel's arithmetical statement CON(ZF)?

Comment: Yes. Because ZF proves that if a theory has a model, then it is consistent. And if we work in a finite language---like the language of set theory---then we can turn this into an arithmetical statement.

Comment: Could ZFC provide a model for ZF?

Comment: No. From a model of ZF we can canonically create a model of ZFC.

Comment: (by the way it is Torkel Franzén that suggests in his book about Godel's Theorem that one could have a statement S that we can interpret as equivalent to Con(T) in such a way that this equivalence cannot be derived in T, and T could be able to prove S without being inconsistent)

Comment: But such statement is *not* going to be "T has a model". At least not when T is some extension of ZF.

Comment: So we create a new theory T=ZF+"ZF has a transitive model" and then it turns out that T is able to prove that there must be a countable transitive model?

Comment: Yes, ZF+"There is a transitive model" implies the existence of a countable transitive model.

Comment: And this proof of the existence is a "non-constructive" proof?

Comment: Well. Again, you just look at the least $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ is a model of ZFC. It's not explicit as saying exactly what it is, but such $\alpha$ is relatively large, even if it is countable, far far beyond what we can fathom and describe "finitarily".

Comment: I guess we are talking about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(set_theory)

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: @Asaf You probably meant to say that the least $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ models ZFC is large, even though it is countable, right? The way you phrased it seems to suggest that it may not be countable, but it provably is - by condensation.

Comment: @Stefan: I believe that I said that explicitly, this is a countable ordinal.

Answer (score 8):

Asaf has given a great answer - let me give another answer which shows a sense in which the answer is no.

Given a theory $T$ (in a finite language to avoid silliness), we can ask if it has a *computable model* - that is, if there is a $\mathcal{A}$ which

- is a model of $T$,
- has domain $\mathbb{N}$ (or a computable subset of $\mathbb{N}$), and
- all the relations and functions in the language are interpreted as computable relations and functions.

It turns out that ${\sf ZF}$ (indeed, *much* weaker than ${\sf ZF}$) has **no computable models**; see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12426/is-there-a-computable-model-of-zfc.

The situation gets even worse for well-founded models: ${\sf ZF}$ has no **hyperarithmetic** well-founded models! "Hyperarithmetic" is a slightly technical definition, but basically anything you can define without using second-order logic is hyperarithmetic.

So I'd consider both these facts as good evidence that ${\sf ZF}$ (and, equally, ${\sf ZFC}$) has no "explicit" model.